# fullcalendarの週表示で文字化け

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, fullcalendar

fullcalendarを使っています。
週表示で月をまたいだ時に文字化けしてしまいます。

[image: enter image descriptionhere]

this code is full calendar settings.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    columnFormat: {
        month: 'ddd',
        week: 'ddd M/D',
        day: 'dddd'
    },
    titleFormat: {
        month: 'YYYY年M月',
        week: 'YYYY年M月D日',
        day: "YYYY年M月D日"
    },
    buttonText: {
        prev:     '＜', // <
        next:     '＞', // >
        prevYear: '＜＜',  // <<
        nextYear: '＞＞',  // >>
        today:    '今日',
        month:    '月',
        week:     '週',
        day:      '日'
    },
    monthNames: ['1月', '2月', '3月', '4月', '5月', '6月', '7月', '8月', '9月', '10月', '11月', '12月'],
    monthNamesShort: ['1月', '2月', '3月', '4月', '5月', '6月', '7月', '8月', '9月', '10月', '11月', '12月'],
    dayNames: ['日曜日', '月曜日', '火曜日', '水曜日', '木曜日', '金曜日', '土曜日'],
    dayNamesShort: ['日', '月', '火', '水', '木', '金', '土'],

});
```

});

Comment: 実装しているHTMLのコードやファイルの文字コード、charasetは何を指定していますか？、また保存して使っていると思いますがインポートしているJSファイルの文字コードは何でしょうか？

Comment: localeが設定されていないようですけど、設定しても変わらないでしょうか??
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/text/locale/

Answer (score 1):

以下のURLでは言語設定が可能なようです。

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/text/lang/

単に日本語表記ということであれば、fullcalendarのソースに含まれているja.jsを
追加で読み込んではいかがでしょうか？

下記の順で読込確認しました。

```
<script src="fullcalendarまでのソースパス/dist/fullcalendar.js"></script>
<script src="fullcalendarまでのソースパス/dist/locale/ja.js"></script>
<script src="schedulerのソース"></script>
```

kamiya555さんと同じです

Answer (score 0):

htmlからインポートするfullcalendarまですべてutf8です。
文字化けするのは月をまたぐときの週表示のみです。
情報ぬけていました。　https://fullcalendar.io/scheduler/　
fullcalendar schedulerを利用しています。

Comment: 情報の追加は、回答として投稿するのではなく、質問を編集する事で行ないます。IDが二つになってしまい苦労なさっているのでしたら、http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts を参考にマージするのがよいです。